# Dell XPS 13 poor performance on battery

Tags: dell-xps

my Dell XPS 13 Notebook (9310, latest BIOS, Windows 10 22H2) has very low performance on battery. If I run prime95 max CPU consumption is at 50% and max. speed at 2 GHz. I can't choose the energy plan "max. performance" in energy settings, just the "balanced" option is available. In the details of balanced plan the max. cpu performance is set 100%, I tried powercfg -restoredefaultschemes and powercfg -duplicatescheme e9a42b02-d5df-448d-aa00-03f14749eb61 , but "max. / high / ultimative performance" plan is still not available. The battery is quite new, ~ 6 month, dell oem.

Does anybody know this problem?

Comment: Did Dell give a 1 year warranty and can you ask for  a replacement ?

Comment: No, it's older than 1 year and I guess it is a software issue

Comment: I meant replacing the battery which you say is 6 months old.

Comment: Have you checked for and installed the latest available drivers?

Answer (score 0):

Group Policy *might* have been set [to disable some Power Options settings](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/gpo-power-plan-prevent-user-from-changing-power/a5db9f95-f487-40a4-9bc7-fb50d1d6be75). [The Windows Club](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/specify-custom-active-power-plan-windows) suggests the following to change that.

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>, type `cmd`, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> to the CMD prompt as Administrator.
- Enter `powercfg/list` to get the plan names and GUID's.
- If the *Max. Performace* option is available, then:

  - Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>, type `gped` and select *gpedit.msc*.
  - Navigate to *Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Power Management*.
  - Double-click `Specify a custom active power plan` in the right pane.
  - In the *Options* pane, enter the GUID for *Max. Performance*.

You can also [create your own customized Power Plan](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-manage-custom-power-plans-windows-10).

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>, type `power opt`, and select *Power Options*.
- Click on *Create a power plan.*.
- Select a plan name or enter a new name.
- Follow each step to create the new plan.

[image: Create a Power Plan]

- In particular, under *Change advanced power settings*, set the *Maximum processor state* appropriately for *On battery* and *Plugged in*.

[image: Maximum power settings]

- Set the new plan as the active one.